# Как правильно использовать do/while в нахождении суммы Си?

Tags: c, циклы, while

[image: i++;]

n=1,2,3,4,5

У меня есть задача - написать код данной суммы с использованием цикла do/while,но выводит неправильный результат.В чем может быть ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
#include <conio.h> 
  
#include <math.h> 

int main()
{
    int i=1,j,n,K,T;
    float y = 0;
    double S,P; 
    K=1;S=0;
    
    
do{
     P=1;
       j=1;
       do{
        P=P*(j+cos(j));
        j++;
       }while(j<n);
        S=S+((2*n*(sin(n+1)))/P);
        printf(" Ответ %f\n",S);
        y+=S;
        n++;
        P = 0;
      

}while(n< 6);
    printf("Y %f",S);
return 0;
}
```

Неправильный вывод

```
 Ответ 1.180674
 Ответ 1.547148
 Ответ -0.314138
 Ответ -1.878566
 Ответ -2.048845
Y -2.048845
```

Правильный вывод

```
Ответ=1.180674
Ответ=1.412055
Ответ=0.486046
Ответ=0.018544
Ответ=-0.013684
Y 3.083635
```

Comment: y+=S тут плюс не лишний ли? Сумма S уже считается выше. Переменная i не используется. А если называть переменные так же, как в формуле, то искать ошибки намного проще.

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется, тут несколько ошибок

1. вы используете `n`, которое не инициализировано, хотя уже для этого определили переменную `i`, которую инициализировали
2. при вычислении произведение вычисляется до i включительно, а у вас не включительно:

вместо

```
do{
    P=P*(j+cos(j));
    j++;
}while(j<n);
```

надо

```
do{
    P=P*(j+cos(j));
    j++;
}while(j<=i);
```

3. вы выполняете двойное суммирование

вместо

```
S=S+((2*n*(sin(n+1)))/P);
y+=S;
```

надо

```
S=((2*i*(sin(i+1)))/P);
y+=S;
```